# Disable all conventions in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Today I have had, and possibly still have more problems with EF6 built-in conventions. By debugging, I saw that code first EF6 enables all the default conventions available.

Since I have generated a good-looking model mapping with mapper classes, I just don't want conventions to someway alter my data model.

In the specific, I can't run a simple `SELECT` query because of a spurious column `Extent1.LinkedEntity_id` that gets into the SQL, when the FK column is correctly mapped as `linkedentity` and I have no reason to use a different name in my database.

For clearness: this code-first model is reverse engineered from a DB-first. Database rules and I can't change its design.

Question: how do I disable all conventions at once? Seems I can't find a `.Clear` method in `DbModelBuilder.Conventions`

Comment: Why do you use code-first if the DB exists and can't be changed? That looks like a case for database-first to me.

Comment: It's a long story. Basically we maintain a **product**, not a project. There is no single DB: the DB must be deployed, maintained and migrated at each customer site where the application is installed. Really, it's a long story that started with a bulk insert failure using 2 different EF utility libraries.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't have this problem before I ported the EDMX model to code first

Comment: @Sefe CodeFirst is a confusing name. you can use DbContext API fine with already existing databases.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I know. OP wants to use code first though to deploy on the customer machines. At least that's how I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way of removing them. But, it could be possible to do using reflection. Find all Conventions and then call Remove on them. Something like this should help:

```cs
    private void RemoveAllConventions(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        var conventions = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.GetInterface("IConvention") != null));


        var remove = typeof(ConventionsConfiguration).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Remove" && m.ContainsGenericParameters).First();
        foreach (var item in conventions)
        {
            try
            {
                remove.MakeGenericMethod(item).Invoke(modelBuilder.Conventions, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

And then in your OnModelCreating:

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        RemoveAllConventions(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Feel free to iterate more on this concept and report back your findings.

Comment: Hi, this was the correct solution to my question (even though I had to make a little tweak), but anyway for sake of discussion it didn't solve my root problem. I hope to upgrade to EF7 someday, but that means a rewrite