# Invalid column name 'ContactId'. Invalid column name 'ContactId1'

Tags: sql-server, database, linq, foreign-keys, .net-core

I am facing this issue since few days and can't figure it out.

I try to create a new Customer by posting this json code to my API and it throw my this error : ***"Invalid column name 'ContactId'. Invalid column name 'ContactId1'."***

```
{
    "sameAsCompanyAddress": true,
    "billingAddress": { line1: "A", suburb: "A", state: "A", postcode: "A" },
    "companyAddress": { line1: "C", suburb: "C", state: "C", postcode: "C" },
    "companyContacts": [
        { firstName: "A", lastName: "A", position: "A", mobile: "A", phone: "A", email: "A" },
        { firstName: "B", lastName: "B", position: "B", mobile: "B", phone: "B", email: "B" }
    ],
    "complianceDocuments": [],
    "keyContact": { firstName: "C", lastName: "C", position: "C", mobile: "C", phone: "C", email: "C" },
    "rating": 1,
    "sameAsCompanyAddress": true,
    "tradeName": "C"
}
```

I think that this is a foreign key problem but can't find which one or what I am missing …

**My database table is like this :**

[image: Customer Table]

[image: CustomerContact Table]

[image: CompanyContact Table]

**My Context is like this :**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Abn).HasColumnType("char(11)");

    entity.Property(e => e.Acn).HasColumnType("char(9)");

    entity.Property(e => e.CreditLimit).HasColumnType("money");

    entity.Property(e => e.Rating).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");

    entity.Property(e => e.SameAsCompanyAddress).HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.BillingAddress)
        .WithMany(p => p.CustomerBillingAddress)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.BillingAddressId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Customer_Address1");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.CompanyAddress)
        .WithMany(p => p.CustomerCompanyAddress)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyAddressId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Customer_Address");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.KeyContact)
        .WithMany(p => p.CustomerNavigation)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.KeyContactId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Customer_CompanyContact");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.PrimaryContact)
        .WithMany(p => p.Customer)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.PrimaryContactId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Customer_CustomerContact");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerContact>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.CustomerNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.CustomerContact)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.CustomerId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_CustomerContact_Customer");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyContact>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Phone).IsUnicode(false);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Subcontractor)
        .WithMany(p => p.CompanyContact)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubcontractorId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_KeyContact_Subcontractor");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Supplier)
        .WithMany(p => p.CompanyContact)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.SupplierId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_KeyContact_Supplier");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Customer)
        .WithMany(p => p.CompanyContact)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.CustomerId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_KeyContact_Customer");
});
```

Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT :**

Here is the generated query :

```
INSERT INTO [Customer] ([Abn], [AccountStatusId], [Acn], [ArchivalDate], [BillingAddressId], [CompanyAddressId], [ContactId], [ContactId1], [CreditApplicationReceived], [CreditLimit], [KeyContactId], [LegalEntity], [PrimaryContactId], [PurchaseOrderRequired], [Rating], [RegisteredDate], [TradeName])
      VALUES (@p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34);
      SELECT [Id], [SameAsCompanyAddress]
      FROM [Customer]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'ContactId'. Invalid column name 'ContactId1'.
```

Comment: The error looks like its coming from an `SqlException`.  Can you use a debugger or profiller to see the generated query.

Comment: Added the generated query, looks like he is trying to insert this two columns [ContactId], [ContactId1] in Customer …

Comment: Or don't do the correct mapping between Customer and CompanyContact

Comment: I'm more familiar with EF7, but it could be a problem with EF6 built-in conventions.  Maybe try [removing them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164886/disable-all-conventions-in-ef6) and see what happens.  As the bad columns are called ContactId maybe you have superfluous Customer navigation properties in the CustomerContact / CompanyContact models.

Comment: I am using EF7 with .Net Core 2.0 so I can't remove Conventions like this, any other way in mind ? Thank you for your time @pariesz